# Dúvida a respeito de consulta de campo float (ruby on rails com mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá, tenho uma dúvida referente a banco de dados com rails.

Se eu declaro que um campo é "float", quando eu fazer a consulta, eu preciso usar o ".to_float" para que o rails entenda o tipo deste campo?

Por exemplo, neste cálculo:

```html
def self.tipe(a)
  pro = ProAttr.where(:pro_id => pro.id).first

  percent_completed_calculated_aggregate = (pro.aggregate_effort.to_float / pro.to_float) * 100
```

Comment: Depende de como você declarou ele quando gerou a Model. Se você fez um `rails generate scaffold ProAttr pro_id:integer aggregate_effort:float`, ele vai entender que é um float. Caso contrário vc terá que chamar o método to_float.

Comment: hmm, saquei, então é esse o motivo hehe, eu sempre crio tabelas direta sem o scaffold, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos!

Comment: Você pode criar diretamente a tabela também. Mas para uso do framework é interessante você dar pelo menos um `rails generate model Model attr1:type1 attr2:type2 --no-migration`, de modo que o --no-migration impede que você crie uma nova tabela ao dar o `db:migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *Rails* trabalha com campos de ponto `flutuante de modo` transparente, então você não precisa fazer essa conversão explicita. Um detalhe, para as migrações do *Rails* `pontos flutuantes` são trabalhados de maneira genérica como `decimal`.

Criação do model ficaria algo como:

```
rails g model ProAttr aggregate_effort:decimal
```

Para esse tipo de campo existem opções extras ([type modifiers](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers)) como `precision` e `scale`.

Onde `precision` é o total de dígitos que seu decimal pode ter e `scale` é a quantidade de número depois do separador decimal (ponto neste caso).

Para gerar já com esses modificadores ficaria assim

```
rails g model ProAttr 'aggregate_effort:decimal{5,2}'
```

Caso você precise adicionar um campo decimal na migração, algo assim:

```
add_column :pro_attrs, :aggregate_effort, :decimal, precision: 5, scale: 2
```

Fazendo assim você vai ter menos dor de cabeça com campos de ponto flutuante.